# Parse LocalDataStorage instead of DB

Tags: parse-platform

I love parse

Can I use "pinning" on ParseObjects in such a way that you pin them on creation and never unpin them?

Is there any drawback to this approach for instance if there is like 1k objects?

The reasoning behind this is that I would not need to use a typical SQLlite to store objects locally on my own.

Thanks

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore-pin